# How do I test against a different database in .net using nunit

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, unit-testing, nunit

I want to create unit tests for my project
In order to not interfere with my development database I want to run the tests against a different "test" database which tables I will truncate after each test is performed.
I am using NUnit as my test framework. Is there a way to switch to a test database when I run the tests?

Comment: How are you creating your database connection now? Are you using `SqlConnection`, Entity Framework, dependency injection, ... ?

Comment: I am using entity framework with dependency injection using  IUnityContainer.

Comment: @Itayk: you can create an in-memory database using Effort. For a detailed walkthrough, take a look on my blog: http://www.vannevel.net/2015/02/26/11/

Comment: Share your sample code of class you want to test and dependent classes which are called by test class so that we can suggest you a solution how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

1. Create a test DB similar to the dev one.
2. Add a connection string with labeled as test DB.
3. Created a DBContext wrapper interface.
4. Created two implementations one for dev and one for tests.
5. Used the UnityContainer (for dependency injection)  in order to select the different DBs in test environment and in dev environment.